# Outer Glow Effect for Text C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i want to have outer glow text in a label for my winform application some thing like:
[image]

i searched for it in stackoverflow and I found this:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)

{

  //Create a bitmap in a fixed ratio to the original drawing area.

  Bitmap bm=new Bitmap(this.ClientSize.Width/5, this.ClientSize.Height/5);

  //Create a GraphicsPath object. 

  GraphicsPath pth=new GraphicsPath();

  //Add the string in the chosen style. 

  pth.AddString("Text Halo",new FontFamily("Verdana"),(int)FontStyle.Regular,100,new Point(20,20),StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

  //Get the graphics object for the image. 

  Graphics g=Graphics.FromImage(bm);

  //Create a matrix that shrinks the drawing output by the fixed ratio. 

  Matrix mx=new Matrix(1.0f/5,0,0,1.0f/5,-(1.0f/5),-(1.0f/5));

  //Choose an appropriate smoothing mode for the halo. 

  g.SmoothingMode=SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

  //Transform the graphics object so that the same half may be used for both halo and text output. 

  g.Transform=mx;

  //Using a suitable pen...

  Pen p=new Pen(Color.Yellow,3);

  //Draw around the outline of the path

  g.DrawPath(p,pth);

  //and then fill in for good measure. 

  g.FillPath(Brushes.Yellow,pth);

  //We no longer need this graphics object

  g.Dispose();

  //this just shifts the effect a little bit so that the edge isn't cut off in the demonstration

  e.Graphics.Transform=new Matrix(1,0,0,1,50,50);

  //setup the smoothing mode for path drawing

  e.Graphics.SmoothingMode=SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

  //and the interpolation mode for the expansion of the halo bitmap

  e.Graphics.InterpolationMode=InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

  //expand the halo making the edges nice and fuzzy. 

  e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm,ClientRectangle,0,0,bm.Width,bm.Height,GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

  //Redraw the original text

  e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Black,pth);

  //and you're done. 

  pth.Dispose();

}
```

but the **PROBLEM IS I CAN NOT MOVE IT** please help me i need it to be movable and I want to be able to change it's size. the code above, just adds it automatically to somewhere in my form but I want to move that.
thank you

Comment: Perhaps this might work [Move Controls on a Form at Runtime](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31840/Move-Controls-on-a-Form-at-Runtime)

Comment: the code is in the form's paint event not in other controls event, actually it'll add a string to the form's client area but I'm not able to change the position correctly (i want to tell it where and which font size)

Comment: @CleverWolf Please use the last revision. Contains some important fixes. See the comments on my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better approach is to create a custom control for this to use/add some relevant drawing properties. Mainly, the Font and color of the text, the size and color of the outline. Then, you can lay out the custom control in any container at any location and with any size.

Here's a simple example.

```cs
[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class GlowTextLabel : Control
{
    private Color outlineColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
    private int outlineSize = 1;

    public GlowTextLabel() : base()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
            ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
            ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
    }

    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Highlight")]
    public Color OutlineColor
    {
        get => outlineColor;
        set
        {
            if (outlineColor != value)
            {
                outlineColor = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
        
    [DefaultValue(1)]
    public int OutlineSize
    {
        get => outlineSize;
        set
        {
            if (outlineSize != value)
            {
                outlineSize = Math.Max(1, value);
                Invalidate();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

        var w = Math.Max(8, ClientSize.Width / 5);
        var h = Math.Max(8, ClientSize.Height / 5);

        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(w, h))
        using (var gp = new GraphicsPath())
        using (var sf = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic))
        {
            sf.Alignment = sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            gp.AddString(Text, 
                Font.FontFamily, (int)Font.Style, GetEmFontSize(Font), 
                ClientRectangle, sf);
               
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            using (var m = new Matrix(1.0f / 5, 0, 0, 1.0f / 5, -(1.0f / 5), -(1.0f / 5)))
            {
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                g.Transform = m;

                using (var pn = new Pen(OutlineColor, OutlineSize))
                {
                    g.DrawPath(pn, gp);
                    g.FillPath(pn.Brush, gp);
                }
            }

            e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            // Optional for wider blur...
            // e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 
                ClientRectangle, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, 
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            using (var br = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
                e.Graphics.FillPath(br, gp);
        }
    }
}

private float GetEmFontSize(Font fnt) =>
    fnt.SizeInPoints * (fnt.FontFamily.GetCellAscent(fnt.Style) +
    fnt.FontFamily.GetCellDescent(fnt.Style)) / fnt.FontFamily.GetEmHeight(fnt.Style);
```

Rebuild, find the `GlowTextLabel` control on the ToolBox under your project's components group, drop an instance, try the `Font`, `ForeColor`, `OutlineColor`, and `OutlineSize` properties with different values.

Pen width 1.

[image: SO74232522A]

Pen width 10.

[image: SO74232522B]

Pen width 20.

[image: SO74232522C]

Comment: Thank you very much it worked for me!
I am working on changing it's backcolor from black to transparent

Comment: @Jimi Jimziii the code slayer! Good morning/afternoon. I haven't `InitializeComponent()` my brain yet. I found something however and fixed it. If something else, edit or tell me what. Stop teasing me :) . A part from that, try it with `gp.Widen(pn);` fancy result.

Comment: I think it's slightly better with `gp.Widen(new Pen(Color.White, OutlineSize / 3.25f));`. Could be set as an option :) (sure, right, you'll dispose of the Pen later) -- As per the problem (which is huge), you **HAD** this: `using (var sf = StringFormat.GenericTypographic) {...}` (now semi-fixed) => since `StringFormat.GenericTypographic` is `static`, you were altering the rendering of all code that uses it, application-wide. The correct form would be `using (var sf = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic))`, to make convenient use of the pre-set

Comment: @Jimi Agree, that was a big one. As for the other enhancements, please keep the comments so the OP and future readers take them into account.. Thank you Jim and tell no one :)